# Rails ActiveSupport::JSON causes Illegal Instruction error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activesupport

I'm trying to encode something in my rails project into JSON, but it seems like any call to any JSON API in Rails causes WEBrick to throw a `"Illegal Instruction"` error.

My code was:

```
@nodes = Node.all
j = ActiveSupport::JSON
@json = j.encode(@nodes)
```

I don't understand why I get this error. Can someone please help?

Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm also using `mysql2spatial` adapter because my `Node` class contains a field with type `GEOMETRY` (mysql spatial extensions).

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a stack trace?  Any indication of the last thing it did before the throwing the error?

Comment: And Node is a ActiveRecord object? Then you can use Node.all.to_json.

Comment: Node is the model class. @nodes is the array of all of the nodes in the database. There really isn't any stack trace. Rails simply crashes (well WEBbrick does) and just gives me a flat out "Illegal Instruction" error. Very frustrating because I can't even trace it. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON gem requires compiled extensions, so it's possible that your version isn't compiled for the architecture or OS you're currently using. You may want to re-install it and see if that resolves the problem.

Ruby itself rarely throws exceptions, but compiled extensions do this much more frequently, especially if compiled against a different set of system libraries.

Comment: Hi tadman, I thought that was the error, but when I try to do the exact same thing with a different set of data (non-spatial data), it works fine. I don't understand why spatial data would cause errors. Rendering xml works perfectly fine, and it even shows "Point(lat,lon)" in the xml, showing that the adapter is working. Anymore help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The XML rendering is done through a different module than JSON, so it could be a bad JSON gem installation like I suggested. You could try using a different JSON library, or a different Ruby, such as through [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). If you have a unit test which exhibits this behavior, it's not too hard to narrow it down further through a process of elimination.

Comment: Hi tadman, thanks for your response. I'm very confused as to installing rails with rvm. I have 1.9.2-p180 installed on my machine, but that was through compiling from the source. How can I reinstall the JSON gem and try again? This error is ridiculously frustrating. Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: The usual procedure is to declare `gem 'json'` in your `Gemfile` and have `bundle install` take care of the rest.